# Laravel: Limit only 1 record from the 2nd table using eloquent join

Tags: mysql, laravel, join, groupwise-maximum, lateral-join

I have a two tables `colors` and `color_translations` with structure like this:

**colors**

| id | created_at | updated_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-08-25 | NULL |
| 2 | 2021-09-01 | NULL |

**color_translations**

| id | color_id ​ | locale | title | url |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ​1 | 1 | en | blue | blue-cat |
| ​2 | 1 | fr | bleu | bleu-cat |
| ​3 | 1 | de | blau | blau-cat |
| ​4 | 2 | de | rot | rot-cat |
| ​5 | 2 | fr | rouge | rouge-cat |

I want to merge the `colors` table with only one of the record from `color_translations` table, the record will be based on the **locale** column, it will look at the **en**  `locale` records first, if not exists then take from **fr** `locale` , then **de** `locale`

| id | created_at | updated_at | locale | title | url |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-08-25 | NULL | en | blue | blue-cat |
| 2 | 2021-09-01 | NULL | fr | rouge | rouge-cat |

i tried to do it like this using my eloquent model:

```
 $this->colorsModel
    ->select( 
        [
            'colors.*',
            'color_translations.locale as locale', 
            'color_translations.title as title',
            'color_translations.url as url'
        ]   
    )
    ->leftJoin ('color_translations', function ($query) {
        $query->on('colors.id', '=', 'color_translations.color_id')
         ->orderByRaw('FIELD(color_translations.locale, "en", "fr", "de)')
         ->limit(1);
    })->get();
```

using above code instead of having 2 records I'm getting all 5 records from the **color_translations** table

Comment: Try adding group by on column locale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much `laravel` but the query should look like this:

(Using technique described by @Bill Karwin [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group-mysql) with the best performance)

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.locale, t2.title, t2.url
FROM colors t1
         LEFT OUTER JOIN color_translation t2 ON t1.id = t2.color_id
         LEFT OUTER JOIN color_translation t3 ON t2.color_id = t3.color_id
                             AND FIELD(t2.locale, 'en', 'fr', 'de') > FIELD(t3.locale, 'en', 'fr', 'de')
WHERE t3.id IS NULL;
```

Note This way in the future if you add any new locales, that locale will be the highest priority as `FIELD()` returns 0 for values that are not specified. I suggest that you make sure every time you run this query in your application.

---

My effort trying to write it in `laravel`:

```
$this->colorsModel
    ->select( 
        [
            'colors.*',
            't2.locale as locale', 
            't2.title as title',
            't2.url as url'
        ]   
    )
    ->leftJoin ('color_translations AS t2', function ($query) {
        $query->on('colors.id', '=', 't2.color_id')
    })->leftJoin ('color_translations AS t3', function ($query) {
        $query->on('t2.color_id', '=', 't3.color_id');
        $query->on(DB::raw('FIELD(t2.locale, \'en\', \'fr\', \'de\')'), '>', DB::raw('FIELD(t3.locale, \'en\', \'fr\', \'de\')'));
    })->whereNull('t3.id')->get();
```

Comment: (`LATERAL` is not available until 8.0.14.)

Comment: is there a way to put this using the eloquent model ?

Comment: Groupwise max:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max

Answer (score 0):

You can use the case in orderby raw query. That will pick any one from the options.

```
$this->colorsModel
                    ->select(
                        [
                            'colors.*',
                            'color_translations.locale as locale',
                            'color_translations.title as title',
                            'color_translations.url as url'
                        ]
                    )
                    ->leftJoin ('color_translations', function ($query) {
                        $query->on('colors.id', '=', 'color_translations.color_id')
                            ->orderByRaw('FIELD(color_translations.locale, CASE  WHEN (color_translations.locale  = "en") THEN en 
                            WHEN (color_translations.locale  = "fr")  THEN fr 
                            ELSE de )')
                            ->limit(1);
                    })->get();
```

Comment: Not working, i'm still getting the same result

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with SQL/Eloquent, without impacting performance, you can indeed use a orderBy by querying all the translations:

```
$locales_ordered = ['en', 'fr', 'nl'];
array_walk($locales_ordered, function(&$x) {$x = "'$x'";});
$query = Colors::with([ 'translations' => function ($q) use ($locales_ordered) {
     $q->orderByRaw('FIELD(colors_translations.locale,' . implode(',', $locales_ordered) . ') ASC')->first();
        } ])
  ->first();
$translation = $query->first()->translations->first();
```

This will get the first associated translation, ordered by your custom locale list order, and so locale fallback. Assuming you have proper Models and a `translations` relationship (`color hasMany color_translations`) between your Model and the translated Model.

The `array_walk` is to put double-quotes around values for the `orderByRaw` with `FIELD` using strings.

You can wrap it in a scoped function on your `Color` model to query it easily:

```
public function scopeWithFallbackTranslation($query)
{
    $locales_ordered = ['en', 'fr', 'nl']; //todo get from helper class, headers, ssession etc..
    array_walk($locales_ordered, function(&$x) {$x = "'$x'";});
    return $query
        ->with([ 'translations' => function ($q) use ($locales_ordered) {
            $q
                ->orderByRaw('FIELD(email_notification_senders_translations.locale,' . implode(',', $locales_ordered) . ') ASC')
                ->first();
        } ]);
}
```

Then call it: `Color::withFallbackTranslation()->where(stuff)->get()`

Note that the `->translations` will still be a Collection, and so need a `->first()` (and empty check). You could get a single object using a custom attribute on the Color model for example.